# Will finally run after return?

Tags: c#, exception, return, try-catch

I have this block of code:

```
try{
    this.connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return true;
}
catch(Exception exc){
    throw exc;
}
finally{
    this.connection.Close();
}
```

I know that if the `catch` throws the exception, the `finally` block will run anyways.

But what about the return in the `try`?

If the `try` block returns `true`, will the `finally` block close my connection?

Is this safe?

Comment: Why not reading MSDN on finally (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does. It is safe to work as you do now.

It executes the `finally` **after you exit the code block**, no matter if that is caused by a `return` or not.

Answer (score 5):

MSDN states

> **finally** is used to guarantee a statement block of code executes regardless of how the preceding **try** block is **exited**.

So, yes.